# Post Video on Vine Social Site

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, vine

I am working on app where I have to upload the media on Vine [Vine](https://vine.co/). I have tried following API and succesfully able to login.

```
NSString *abcd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vineapp.com/users/authenticate"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:abcd];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [request1 setURL:url];
    [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                                stringBoundary];
    [request1 addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
      // final boundary
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"myuser" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"pass" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request1 setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"responseString..:%@",responseString);
    if (urlData!=nil) {
        if(NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization"))
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                         options:0
                         error:&error];

            if(error) {  }
            if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            {
                NSDictionary *results = object;
                  NSLog(@"results..:%@",results);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read this documentation for the login process.[Vine API Reference](https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference)

But I am unable to implement logout and upload media API's.

Please If anyone has any suggestion then please let me know. And also tell me is it right way to post video on vine or is there any other API or library available for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi sudha, have you got the solution to upload media on vine?

Comment: Hi Sudha, can you tell me how you have performed login with vine? I referred the Vine API Reference you mentioned but it doesn't seems to be working for me.

Comment: @MilanGupta The above code is perfectly fine for login. Please check your code again. There will be missing something in your code. https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement post method to upload video and delete method to logout.In question you mention that you are implementing get method call. So change method type to Delete, Post , Get according to API.

Comment: how to implement delete API